# Out of order data in TCP

Tags: java, networking, tcp, protocols, apache-mina

I've an application that's using Apache mina library for communicating based on TCP. The apache mina library provides a callback with IOBuffer that contains data coming over the network, however often times the data is received out of order or redundantly. I skimmed through the TCP protocol and it says that the protocol always ensures delivery of the data in correct order. The company that provided the APIs for their server claim that they are using TCP/IP for sending the response back however before sending the response back their server doesn't care about confirming if the client (in this case my application/apache mina library) is connected to the server. So the server just fires off the message and moves on.

If I'm not mistaken, that's the UDP protocol's behavior. My question is, if the server is using TCP for sending the response back:

1. Why do I get out of order data (it's rare but happens one in a while)?
2. How can a machine that's using TCP protocol just fire and forget about the data without making sure the receiver device is connected to it before sending the data?
3. Is this really TCP or UDP or some variation of TCP protocol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Mina does asynchronous messaging over the top of various transports including TCP.

Since Mina is asynchronous, out-of-order delivery should be expected.

> Why do I get out of order data (it's rare but happens one in a while)?

One possible explanation is that multiple TCP streams are being used.  Data delivered using one TCP stream will be delivered in order, but if multiple streams are used, data in one stream could "overtake" data on another stream, in the TCP stacks on the sending or receiving end, on the network, or in the client side library.

> How can a machine that's using TCP protocol just fire and forget about the data without making sure the receiver device is connected to it before sending the data?

Because ... reliable delivery is not a basic attribute of Mina.

If you are using Mina to talk to a service with a particular application protocol, then that protocol will determine will determine whether "sending the data before checking the receiver is connected" is allowed / will work or not.   For example, it won't for an HTTP response, because an HTTP response is sent on a connection that was previously established to send the request.

Actually, it seems that there are a variety of ways to use Mina.  Some involve an application protocol; e.g. see `HttpClientCodec` and `HttpServerCodec`.  Others don't.

> Is this really TCP or UDP or some variation of TCP protocol?

If they say that TCP is being used as transport, then it is.  However, Mina is neither TCP or UDP.  It is Mina.  It **hides** the details of the transport.

---

Bottom line, if you want the reliability / in-order delivery properties of TCP/IP, you should probably use them directly.  Mina is providing higher performance than conventional TCP/IP over a synchronous socket by *relaxing* the normal properties of a (single) stream-based transport.

Comment: The server is not using Mina. They claim to be using TCP sockets. My java application which is a client is using apache mina

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Please correct me if I'm wrong. I always thought that the HTTP servers and/or TCP sockets always check if the client is connected to them before sending the response back. For instance in case of TCP, the tcp sockets on the servers are supposed to receive the ack from the client that it has received the data otherwise the server will send it back until client sends the ack that it received the data. Similarly http on the server will wait for a certain time until the client is connected until the http client has received it. Isn't this the case?

Comment: Yes.  That is correct.  What protocol are you actually using?

Comment: The company who's server apis I'm using are claiming that they are using TCP protocol for sending the response back to the client but they also said that for sending the response back, the server just fires and forgets that means if the client is not connected at the time the server sent the response, the server will never retry to send it back. That's why I'm confused, if that's how real TCP works or if there are variations of TCP that the server might be using

Comment: TCP can be used like that.  It depends on the application protocol.   What is the application protocol?

Comment: I don't understand "TCP can be used like that. It depends on the application protocol". How can it be TCP if it's firing and forgetting and not taking acknowledgements into consideration. On the application side, I'm using TCP protocol using Apache mina

Comment: Here is an example of fire and forget in Java:  `try { OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream(); os.write(bytes); os.close(); } catch (IOException ex) { /* ignore */ }`.  This code will not know if the data was received.  It doesn't care.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response but if the code doesn't care or implement measures to ensure if the data is received by the destination, how can we call it TCP? The basic idea behind TCP is reliable data transmission based on acknowledgements. If there are no measures for ensuring reliable data transfer and/or validity of data then isn't it the UDP protocol?

Comment: The server / application is not the protocol.  The transport protocol (TCP) provides certain properties that (in this case) the application doesn't make use of.  That's fine.  That doesn't change the protocol.  The protocol is *still* TCP/IP.  (Consider this story: "A bicycle has pedals.  But I can take my bicycle to the top of a hill, take my feet off the pedals and .... wheee!!"   Does this mean that my bicycle is no longer a bicycle while I am free-wheeling down the hill?)

Comment: That clarifies things allot. One last question, if someone is not utilizing the acknowledgement and reliable delivery features offered by TCP, then what's the benefit of using TCP when its "acting" like UDP?

Comment: Well, you still get the benefit that the server-side TCP stack will attempt to retransmit dropped packets that are part of the "message" ... so long as the client is still trying to read them.